# uninstalling mongo

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am having trouble uninstalling mongo from a 64 bit EC2.
In /usr/bin I have mongo and mongod amongst others.
When I type mongo from anywhere it opens the shell at version 1.8.
I now downloaded 2.0.2 and in that folder when I run mongo it opens up version 2.0.2

My question is how do I purge mongo fully so I can install 2.0.2 without coming across the old 1.8 version?

EDIT: I believe I used yum (it was a while ago), and I think the ec2 is fedora.

Comment: what distribution are you on?

Comment: Did you use yum or apt-get when you originally installed mongodb (version 1.8)?

Comment: For reference: https://www.mongodb.com/basics/uninstall-mongodb

Answer (score 47):

1.Stop Mongo DB using -

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

2.Remove Packages using -

```
sudo yum erase $(rpm -qa | grep mongodb-org)
```

3.Remove Data Directories using -

```
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongo
```

Answer (score 21):

yum erase mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This helped... Also i had to remove the other dependencies which were installed using yum: `yum erase mongo-10gen-mongos mongo-10gen-tools mongo-10gen-shell`

Answer (score 19):

I needed to run a `yum list installed | grep mongo` then yum remove those packaged

Answer (score 9):

This should work

```
rpm -qa | less | grep mongo
```

using that command will give you the mongo packages you have installed, after that you can do

```
rpm -qa | less | grep mongo | xargs yum remove // <-- this will remove all packages automatically
```

but can also remove all of them Manually

Comment: This worked like a charm on CentOS 8 with CWP. I just had to add the "-y" switch after "yum" to make it all automatic :)

Answer (score 5):

this gets the job done easily

```
sudo yum erase mongodb-org*
```

Answer (score 4):

First stop the mongo service

> sudo service mongod stop

Then remove the packages

> sudo yum erase $(rpm -qa | grep mongodb-org)

Then remove the log(data) directories

> sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
>
> sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongo

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu users:

First, stop the service of MongoDB and then try uninstalling mongod.

Then, type these commands to uninstall mongodb:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `dnf` command to list and uninstall mongodb from my EC2 servers (RedHat  Enterprise Linux 8). Hope this helps for the RHEL8 users.

> `DNF`_ is the next upcoming major version of `YUM`_, a package manager
> for RPM-based Linux distributions. It roughly maintains CLI
> compatibility with YUM and defines a strict API for extensions and
> plugins.

For further reading about DNF usage...

> https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html

To list down the mongodb installations (Use sudo if required)

```
sudo dnf list installed|grep mongodb
```

[image]

To uninstall/remove mongodb

```
sudo dnf remove mongodb-org
```

[image]

Then run the list command again to see if the installation is successful. It shouldn't show any mongodb-org packages if the uninstallation was successful.

```
sudo dnf list installed|grep mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `yum remove mongodb` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that already, thanks.sudo yum remove mongod
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: mongodb
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
0 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No Packages marked for removal

Comment: Ok if its saying no match for mongodb try: "yum list installed" and then yum remove whatever says mongo

Answer (score 0):

Steps to uninstall MongoDB:

1. `sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen`
3. `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall mongo db by this code
Uninstalling existing MongoDB packages

Since I'm not 100% what you've got installed, I suggest the following to make sure everything is uninstalled:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: He said it's probably a Fedora, not a Debian based dist.

Answer (score 0):

First Stop the service of MongoDB and then try uninstalling mongod.

Answer (score -4):

Type `which mongo` This will show the executable path. Delete all the mongo related binaries in that path, then install the new version and copy all those binaries to `/usr/bin` directory. After this you will be able to access it without any issues.

Comment: If you installed via a package manager, you should always try and remove via a package manager, or the package manager metadata will remain out of date and you'll always have issues.